# Will SharePoint 2010 support Web Service Access?

Tags: web-services, sharepoint-2010

It's my understanding SharePoint 2010 has introduced a new JavaScript API, a brand new assembly for Silverlight clients, but does anybody know if there will be still support for good old Web Service Access?

By old services, I am referring to the old interface
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878586.aspx

Comment: You would know if they were terminating Web Service access. Those things are used all the time.

Comment: Rumor has it some methods in Microsoft.SharePoint have not even been marked as [Obsolete] but rather completely removed.  One can only wonder about WebServices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes SharePoint 2010 still has web services. Review [this MSDN section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee705814(office.14).aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially the new API's are there to help client side code run interesting code without having to use the Web Services. If you have ever tried utilising a webservice from Javascript you can understand the pain the new API's are trying to prevent.

Comment: Calling any webservice is indeed a bit painful from JavaScript. Thankfully there are wrappers such as this one http://darrenjohnstone.net/2008/07/22/examples-for-the-sharepoint-and-office-live-javascript-api/#topic-5 that makes life easier when calling WS from JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

The Web services are still supported. However, the data-retrieval oriented Web services should be considered semi-deprecated. Going forward, you shoul use either the client object model or ADO.NET Data Services to get data from a client.

Comment: +1 Thank you, it will take us a while to migrate all that CAML stuff to the new model ...

Comment: What is semi-depricated? Any references?

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to figure out how to administrate the whole thing with whatever APIs are available. The MSDN documentation seems like what I need, except I feel stupid and can't find where those APIs are on my server. There are no URLs to be seen in the documentation. Am I blind?